Error with angular-css Plugin: text-info-detail Class Not Found in Tailwind CSS Setup with my-design Package
I'm encountering an issue while building my Angular project with Tailwind CSS and the my-design package. The project setup involves importing various CSS files from the my-design package into my styles.scss file.
Here is the relevant portion of my styles.scss:
/*! tailwind */
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/css/colors-rgb-default.css';
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/css/colors-rgb-brand.css';
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/tailwind/typography.css';
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/tailwind/base.css';
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/css/globals.css';
@import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/css/reset.css';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

My tailwind.config.js looks like this:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
 content: [
     "./src/**/*.{html,ts,scss}",
     "./node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/**/*.{css,scss}",
 ],
 corePlugins: {
     preflight: false,
 },
 theme: {
     extend: {},
 },
 plugins: [],
 presets: [
     require('my-design/styles'),
 ],
}

During the build process, I encounter the following error:
✘ [ERROR] The `text-info-detail` class does not exist. If `text-info-detail` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive. [plugin angular-css]

node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/tailwind/base.css:2:2:
    2 │   @apply
      ╵   ^

The plugin "angular-css" was triggered by this import

src/styles.scss:4:8:
    4 │ @import '../node_modules/my-design/styles/dist/tailwi...
      ╵         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Details:
In the base.css file from my-design, I see the following code:
body {
 @apply
     font-info
     text-info-detail;

     color: rgb(var(--theme-default-03-secondary-text, theme('colors.theme-default-03-secondary-text')));
}

Questions:
How can I resolve the error related to the text-info-detail class not being recognized?
Is there a specific way to configure Tailwind CSS to work properly with my-design?
Are there any additional steps or configurations I should be aware of when using Tailwind CSS with external design system packages?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
